# Why the minimum element of array is not sorted while using bubble sort?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have recently started python. I have written a function for bubble sort. It works fine. It have only one problem when I use two minimum values. The second one is not sorted correctly.

```
def bubble_sort(arr):
    flag = True
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if flag == False:
            return arr
        flag = False
        for j in range(i, len(arr) - 1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                print(arr[j], arr[j + 1])
                temp = arr[j + 1]
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
                arr[j] = temp
                flag = True
    return arr


print(bubble_sort([1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 1, 6])) //[1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6]
```

I expect the two `1`s in the start but the second is at third position.

Comment: You can not increment the start index of the inner loop, you can only *decrement* the end index of that loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *not* increment the start index each loop, but decrement the end index, like:

```
def bubble_sort(arr):
    flag = True
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if not flag:
            return arr
        flag = False
        for j in range(len(arr) - i):
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1]:
                arr[j+1], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[j+1]
                flag = True
    return arr
```

Each iteration you move the cursor from left to right. That means that if the cursor finds the maximum value, it will move that value to the right end of the list. But the same does *not* hold for the minimum value. If the cursor finds the minimum value, it will only move it *one* position to the left. That is why you should keep starting from the start of the list each iteration.

Comment: I got it.Thank you very much.